# Prototype cells in xcode don't show after I run the app in simulator

Tags: xcode

I am a newbie in xcode developing. I try to create a table view with prototype cells. After I create the table view and add details in the cells , when I run the app in the simulator the information on the cells don't appear. Why? Please explain me in detail. Is there a step by step tutorial that can fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639780/uitableview-with-static-cells-does-not-appear) will answer your question. In short, you probably need to use a Table View Controller instead of a View Controller.

You may also need to switch the Table View's content from **Dynamic Prototypes** to **Static Cells**.

Answer (score 2):

I know its late, but anyone in 2017 still ripping their hair out trying to solve this problem, make sure you are using the correct "identifier" field in the Interface builder to provide your reusable identifier. Interface builder has an "accessibility identifier" and a "reusable identifier" both conveniently labelled in the interface builder as "identifier" which can easily be confused.

See screenshot
[image: XCode Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

you probably forget to put Cell id: Make sure you have used similar Cell ID for your prototype cell in "Show Attribute inspector" and in your implementation in method "`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath"`