# UITextField in UITableViewCell not appearing at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

So I'm working in XCode 5 and iOS 7 and am trying to add editable UITextFields to a series of UITableViewCells. It all looks good on the storyboard, but when I run the app, there's no text visible in the cell and the cell doesn't allow editing.

Screenshot of how it looks in the storyboard:
[image: screenshot]

In the app, it's just a couple of blank cells. Any thoughts?

Comment: what type of table view do you use static cells or dynamic prototypes  tables? have you set datasource to the table view?

Comment: try pinning the width of the cell using nsconstraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please refer to [UITableView with static cells does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639780/uitableview-with-static-cells-does-not-appear)

> One more thing about static cells, they only work in
>   UITableViewController. The Storyboard Editor will let you add them to
>   a Table View object inside a regular UIViewController, but this won’t
>   work during runtime. The reason for this is that UITableViewController
>   provides some extra magic to take care of the data source for the
>   static cells. Xcode even prevents you from compiling such a project
>   with the error message: “Illegal Configuration: Static table views are
>   only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances”.

Comment: Static cells. Looks like I can do this in code by setting the data source, but is there some way to add the text fields in storyboard to avoid a long series of if/elseif/elseif... for a variety of different input types?

Comment: Also, seems to work similarly whether it's static cells or dynamic prototypes. What's functionally the difference?

Comment: I did a quick test on static cells, no need to implement the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  and the cells will be displayed automatically on tableview.      dynamic tables: the cells' data need to be updated during runtime,

Comment: The text fields show up and are editable with static cells and no overriding of cellForRowAtIndexPath? Do you have any insight on what I'm missing?

Comment: I guess you have - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 0;  }   so no cells will be displayed on screen

Comment: I don't have the protocol implemented - took that out because I was trying to just do it in storyboard.

Comment: can you make a demo project and upload to somewhere and see if I can help?  I did a quick demo with only storyboard, no view controllers, with two static cells like you did(no border style), the text fields can be edited

Comment: github.com/nurepnick/test  is just a empty project, I do not see any cells in any of the story board

Comment: Uploaded again - nothing in the iPad storyboard?

Comment: sorry, I checked it does not work, the static cells are not supported on a generic view controller, it will only work with a UITableViewController

Comment: Ah well, guess there's not really a way.

Answer (score 1):

Though I figured it out lately that if your static tableViewCell shows in storyboard but doesn't appear in runtime only because of your UITableViewController class has `numberOfSections()` & `tableView()` function. 
If you really want to show static table view cell then just remove those functions and it'll appear in runtime. you need to just have only `viewDidLoad()` func in your class like this

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```