# UISwitch in static UITableViewCell generates error

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uiswitch

I would like to create a UIViewController with various options, each can be enabled/disabled with a UISwitch.
I'm using Xcode 5 and iOS 7 deployment target.
The UITableView contains static cells. The interface is created in a storyboard.

When I'm adding a UISwitch to a cell (to it's `contentView`) I get this error:

```
Exception while running ibtool: *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: objectID)
```

Isn't it possible to add a UISwitch to a static UITableViewCell? 
When removing the UISwitch the error disappears.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have the exact problem today and I couldn't figure out what is causing my problem because I have added too many items on my view controller. Now I know it is the UISwitch.

But I have resolved the problem, nonetheless.

I disabled the "Accessibility" option and the build was successful.

[image]

But How come the "Accessibility" option becomes an issue of Object Id remains unclear.

Comment: You're right. When I disable the "Accessibility" option the error is gone, too. But my UISwitch isn't visible at runtime. I think the main problem is that I'm using static cells, but without a `UITableViewController`, what seems to be not possible. Do you also tried this with static cells and without a UITableViewController?

Comment: Yes I am using static cell on storyboard. I think I used without UITableViewController before. Now I am using UITableViewController it doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: I switched also to a UITableViewController and now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

For static table cells one has use to a UITableViewController. Static cells are not supported by UITableView.

Another answering this point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428324/42756

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but to the game, but...

If you define a **User Defined Runtime Attribute** to an AutoLayout constraint that is a Placeholder (i.e. removed at build time), you get this error.