# Using a UITableView on a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I've created a `UITableViewController` in Xcode `storyboard` first (with a `UITableView` on it obviously) but since I want also a `UIButton` and segmented control on the same page I replaced the view with a `UIViewController` and `UIView` and then put a `UITableView` on it and moved my already defined (`static`) table cells into it.

However when trying to compile I get the error:

```
.../iPhone.storyboard: Exception while running ibtool: *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: objectID)
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: I think your data source may be nil... That is there is no data in some index...Can you put your tableview creation code

Comment: check for datasoure & delegates are set. If set are the really called?

Comment: This did the trick for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730440/how-to-setup-a-static-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uiview

Answer (score 0):

You can only use static cells with an UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

static cells can only be used with UITableViewController. disable the "`Accessibility`" option and try building again. refer this [UISwitch in static UITableViewCell generates error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230523/uiswitch-in-static-uitableviewcell-generates-error)
for more info

Comment: Where do I disable the Accessibility for the tableview? And more importantly: Is surely is possible to define a custom controller class for the UIView-embedded tableview, is it?

Comment: I see Accessibility is in the Identity inspector. Well, the UITableView shows no such option and for the UIView and table cells they are already disabled.

Comment: I think what In need is this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730440/how-to-setup-a-static-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uiview

Comment: please ignore  the Accessibility option, i think it was for uiswitch. Try using UITableViewController for static cells, Take a viewController and add tableviewcontroller inside another view in that viewcontroller.

Comment: Yep, see my former comment. That was the solution after all. Use a container to embed a tableview controller so that table can use a controller.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could put some code samples to see what's happening, because theoretically speaking you did everything right !!

You must've forgot some variable or something, something is nil. Checkout your wiring between the Storyboard and ViewController.m, that might be a problem.