# How do I get Prototype TableView Content to show in a Tab Bar ViewController?

Tags: ios

I am creating an app for iOS 7 and I am using Storyboard to create the initial views and segues. Because this app will use Tab Bar for the main navigation I started with a Tab Bar Controller. I then added a Table View to that view, so the Table View is nested in the first (default) view controller. Because I am still in the proof of concept phase I am using static content. However, when I set the table cells to static > Basic with a Disclosure Indicator, nothing shows up when I Run the app in the Simulator. Is there something else that needs to be done to get this content to show?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UITableViewController instead of a generic UIViewController. Also lost some time recently trying to make this work until I found out that "Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances".

Read the whole thread here:
[UITableView with static cells does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639780/uitableview-with-static-cells-does-not-appear)

The key excerpt from this thread taken from [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on Storyboards](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2):

"One more thing about static cells, they only work in UITableViewController. The Storyboard Editor will let you add them to a Table View object inside a regular UIViewController, but this won’t work during runtime. The reason for this is that UITableViewController provides some extra magic to take care of the data source for the static cells. **Xcode even prevents you from compiling such a project with the error message: “Illegal Configuration: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances”**."