# uitableviewcell segue don't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, segue

i am new to ios,i write some basic code with storyboard for study.

i have a tabbar controller which have two tab bar item.i want the second item display a tableview,so i drag tableview to the uiviewcontroller,then in the tabview,i add a static table cell.then i drag a uiviewcontroller and a text label in it to display.

i want when i click the tablecell,the program will take me to the uiviewcontroller who has a simple text label,so i add a segue from tablecell to the new uiviewcontroller,but it seems don't work.

my code is  here:[dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozuy71561w0scg6/SlamDunk.zip)
[image: here is my storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the second View Controller a UITableViewController instead of dragging a UITableView to a UIViewController. This is necessary because static Table Views only work on UITableViewControllers.

See same question answered here with references on why it doesn't work in that case: [How do I get Prototype TableView Content to show in a Tab Bar ViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799439/how-do-i-get-prototype-tableview-content-to-show-in-a-tab-bar-viewcontroller/19800753#19800753)

Once you change it to a UITableViewController, drag a new segue from the static cell to your destinationViewController and it should work as you expected.

Comment: i got this error message,Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.

Comment: Got it. You can solve this problem easily with one of two options: [Option 1] Embedd your new UITableViewController in a Navigation Controller by selecting the controller and then clicking on Editor > Embedd In > Navigation Controller. This way the push segue will work. [Option 2] Change the segue style by clicking on it and choosing Modal instead of Push from the Segue Attributes Inspector. Both ways work with slightly different behaviors depending on what user flow you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your modal connection for your  cell and add your to your code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UIViewController *detailController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailController"];

    [self addChildViewController:detailController];
    [detailController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self toViewController:detailController duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

}
```

You have to set `detailController` like StoryBoard ID in interface Builder to your Controller with a label

Comment: i want use storyboard to implement it,or i must write code to do that?can you tell me how to add segue to make it work?