# iOS development - How to display static cells created in Interface Builder with custom Table View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was trying to display something in static cells with a Table View.

First I create a Table View Controller in interface builder with static cells.

I never designate a custom `UITableViewController` class, it works well.

But since I designate it to `MyTableViewController` class, the table view displays nothing.

How to make static cells appear when using a custom `UITableViewController` class?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639780/uitableview-with-static-cells-does-not-appear

Answer (score 0):

In the method:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

you have to get a cell with identifier and then manage it and return it:

```
static NSString *identifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
```

you must set identifier in interface builder..you have to select the cell and write the identifier in the inspector field.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answering. I figure it out by just commenting the table view delegate methods (`UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods) in my custom `UITableViewController` class. I think it may hijacks the table view I built in IB, so once I comment it, it works. It might be done by super class or somewhere.