# iOS todo-tutorial, can't repopulate tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

So yesterday i began learning iOS programming, and i followed the tutorial for the to-do app.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1

I have created my own tablelistviewcontroller as the guide tells me, and all my previous static data is gone when i boot, and the tutorial tells me this

> you’ll notice that it implements three methods—numberOfSectionsInTableView:, tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:, and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. You can get your static data to display again by commenting out the implementations of these methods. Go ahead and try that out if you like.

So i commented out the cellForRowAtIndexPath, it was the only one commented out. And then i got an error at the "reuseIdentifier", so after a time of googling, i have managed to name my cells "Cells" and i ended up with this code,

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cells";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

But everytime i build and start the app, i cant see my previous data, i can see it in my storyboard, but not in app.. And now i am out of ideas and since i am a newbie i believe the solution is pretty easy.

Please notify if you need any additional data.

Comment: What do you mean by `i cant see my previous data`?

Comment: please add this line before return cell to see something in each cell. cell.textLabel.text = @"someText"

Comment: Please look at this section: Display Static Content in a Table View
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/Art/ios_simulator_static_table_view_2x.png

Comment: hey tableview is for displaying data not for saving data.

Comment: hey dreamhawk it is ur storyboard or simulator ?

Comment: 1. your question is not clear about what you want to do and what problem you are facing.
2. if you are trying to use the tableview to display static data, what do you mean by `previous data`?

Comment: hey if u r beginner try to learn through www.raywenderlich.com and www.appcoda.com it is best site for IOS beginner.

Comment: Previous data, with that i mean the static data that i have inserted during the chapter "Display Static Content in a Table View", later in the tutorial i am supposed to create a Custom View Controller, and after this i can no longer see the data since before, and apple tells me that i have to uncomment "cellForRowAtIndexPath" to make it visible again, but it is not working.

Comment: See my answer. I think you really misunderstood the concept of tableView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really misunderstood these lines:

> So why doesn’t your data show up? Table views have two ways of getting
>   data—statically or dynamically. When a table view’s controller
>   implements the required UITableViewDataSource methods, the table view
>   asks its view controller for data to display, regardless of whether
>   static data has been configured in Interface Builder. If you look at
>   XYZToDoListTableViewController.m, you’ll notice that it implements
>   three methods—numberOfSectionsInTableView:,
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:, and
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. You can get your static data to
>   display again by commenting out the implementations of these methods.
>   Go ahead and try that out if you like.

The thing is when you are adding data using your app, the data is no more `static`. It is `dynamic`. `UITableView` doesn't store your data. It just displays it. And when you are using dynamic data, you will need a `datasource` which will give the `tableView` the data to display. You must store the data by some possible storage mechanisms in IOS. Here is a link to one such [tutorial which will get you started with Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started).
Here is a good [tutorial which will get you started with `UITableView`](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) that will display a dynamic data.

The problem is you got the concept totally wrong.

**EDIT**

You might have added something like `<UITableViewDataSource>` in the interface file and may have added the `ViewController` as the datasource for the table(either using ctrl-drag in story board or `tableView.datasource = self;` in the code). Just remove these two and your static content will display again.

Comment: But i haven't added data through the app yet, thats the next part. I have only added data through the storyboard, to the tablecells like its explained in the tutorial. But since apple says "You can get your static data to display again by commenting out the implementations of these methods.", shouldnt i be able to retreive that data again ??

Comment: Im sorry for being a trouble here, where can i see if i might have added <UITableViewDataSource> in the Main.storyboard or added the ViewController as datasource? All i've ctrl-drag is from the "Add"-button to the "Add to-do button" controller.

Comment: found a solution here ; http://stackoverflow.com/a/9952311/889771 , we'll see how far this goes, thanks although for helping such a noob as me... :)